# Are there special conditions allowing VBA for-to loop to let values larger than defined by the "to" parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script, looping through a variable, and doing some data I/O in the loop.
The variable itself is not modified explicitly in the loop or in called functions.
it looks like

```
Private angle As Double
Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()
For angle = 1 To 10 Step 1 
   'some I/O code with system API calls, math, and MS forms manipulation. The "angle is not used there
   ' and then there is an output to the table:
      If Not textbuffer = "" Then
         Cells(1, Fix(angle)).Value = CDbl(Replace(textbuffer, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator))
         If angle > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Weird, more than 10 readings happened"
            Debug.Assert angle > 10
         End If
         drx_success = True
      End If
Next
```

//"FIX" in the above is a pure safety measure from legacy version of what I was doing. In principle it should not produce angle>10 even with decimal arguments like 10.xxxx

There are also tewo control-buttons which may reset the "angle" to 1, or to 10, effectively restarting, or finishing the sequence. But never larger than 10.

```
Private Sub StopButton_Click()
    angle = 10
End Sub

Public Sub btn_Y_callback()
      ' some callback code for script-generated non-AX controls.
      ' it is Public by the rules, but in fact may be called only within the scope of the same worksheet, where it is clicked.
      angle = 1
End Sub
```

The problem is that sometimes, the script writes to the 11th cell, throwing out that alert message.
Actually I never saw this happening than the above buttons were pressed, so that is given just for the whole picture of the loop.

Are there some special conditions when For-two loop may get out of scopes? AFAIK, Vba is purely one-thread procedural engine; so even calling functions on button-click should not distort/skip the for-to loop increment, and end-value check.

The I/O and system calls, particularly the COM-port I/O, and system performance counters, whcih I use, are inside the loop. Of course they work in separate threads. All of them, however, are confined inside the loop. So the loop generally waits for the value return.

My only guess, that the stack may be damaged when making  PtrSafe "kernel32" and "winmm.dll" calls. And only the loop counter is affected.

//funny, I gave all my code to Chatgpt, and it did not find a place where the counter overflow is possible.

Comment: You can try to dimension _angle_ as _integer_ or _long_

Comment: yes. probably. that is just left of the previous iteration. that is not kind of user-oriented  program, but a script for R&D work. And I am lazy checking for types. So "Fix" should have worked. Anyway, even floating point variable, it should not increment more than defined by "To" parameter. Should it? AFAIK, there is no overload of basic operators in VBA, so even 3rd party libraries, they should not change how doube variables are incremented.

Comment: Firstly, it is strange to globally declare a variable which will be incremented as in your code. It should be declared `As Long` inside the procedure. If you want stopping the loop it would be better to declare `boolStop As Boolean`, then place as the first line during the loop `If boolStop then Exit For`. What you say as "effectively restarting will be accomplished by simple calling `CommandButton2_Click`, or place a sub containing the existing code, called by `CommandButton2` or `btn_Y_callback`. No need to use `Step 1`. This is the default increment...

Comment: And it is not possible to have a larger value  "then To" except the case when your code modifies it (somehow). It will be 11 only after finishing the loop, outside of/after it.

Comment: >Firstly, it is strange to globally declare
- Variables are declared globally when it is needed. Believe me, it is a common practive when working with multiple sheet-embedded controls. It should not be a problem. It is very unlikely that any of common VBA COM libs ot macro tools would access this variable by name.

Comment: >As Long
- Do you confirm that floating point veriables may run out of FOR-TO loop scopes? Or this is just a estetique consideration?

Comment: >boolStop As Boolean  - actually I do exactly that. But there are different mechanisms for different scenarios. boolStop - stops. Counter lets the data be fetched normally.

Comment: > simple calling CommandButton2_Click - It requires full interface and data on hold reset. This scenario is implemented. But tampering with the loop inside its scope allows softly restarting or finishing the I/O. I made it unded supposition that the one-threaded code will never interfere with low-level implementation of the FOR-TO loop. I guessed so.

Comment: My latest observation is that may happen when changing focus to another open spreadsheet with no VBA code embedded (when I fill another journal with observations manually). It looks like changing the Excel focus may let For-To loop to run away from its limits... A bug in the implementation? I keep handlers in variables where possible,  the scope of SUBroutine should  also be kept unchanged; I guess so.

Comment: The issue is not that there are globally declared variables in general - global variables have their purpose - the problem ist that a global variable is used as the iteration variable. You can of course base your iteration variable on the global variable for example like this: `Dim i As Long` `For i = angle To 10` - And if a procedure that is called during the loop needs the iteration variable just pass it to said procedure - Having a global variable that simultaneously functions as an iteration variable is really strange. - I'd say the global iteration variable is the most likely issue

Comment: My guess is that some part of the code under some circumstances has the side effect of changing `angle` (which is only possible since it's a globally accessible variable - if angle didn't double as the iteration variable this would most likely not be an issue

Comment: It comes down to perfoming arithmetic with a double and integer or long type which produces rounding errrors. If angle must be double could have a integer or long  variable initialized  to Fix(angle) to control the  loop.  That should also increase performance of the loop.  Also Step 1 isn't required.

Comment: `Dim index as long index = angle` etc should solve the issue of rounding errors due to floating point arithmetic.  And also don't require the Step 1 .  [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) would give that a code inspection warning. Ps I'm having issues with the latest version and had to roll back to a previous version. Apart from that I'd recommend RD to help with coding.

Comment: >Having a global variable that simultaneously functions as an iteration variable is really strange  -  That is dictated by Excel scope hierarchy.  And a short way to control the loop without dangerous forced exits. So take it please as given, that the variable "angle" may be read everywere, but is not modified anywhere intentionally. Unententionally, maybe, but I have no idea how. _And that is the question_. The name is choosen specifically for avoiding incorrect use by supplimentary modules, like solver, or I/O wrappers.

Comment: >produces rounding errrors.   -  Therefore I used Fix()

Comment: >Dim index as long index = angle  --  The idea is that I have an access to the iterator itself, and may set it to the end-value for finishing the cycle preemptively, for example. Diming index = angle makes no sense.

Comment: > don't require the Step 1  --before fix there was a floating point value. So that's just an insurance.

Comment: BTW. Setting it as Long and removing FIX() does not solve the issue.

During the script run tho documents are always open. One of the documents has no scripts in it.

Comment: Another suspicion. I use WINAPI sleep excessively in the loop. unconditionally, and conditionally. Like that: If angle > 1 Then
Sleeper stepwait  End If. May a kernel32 sleep function disrupt the VBA execution?